# Lost Qty number of products from catalog to cart

Tags: forms, magento, checkout, cart, catalog

I was changing some things on my catalog, and on checkout cart, i lost the number of my products.

As i see, in my form data:

```
   form_key:XXXXXXXXXXX
product:712
related_product:
bundle_option[1][]:1
bundle_option_qty[
    1][1]:3
bundle_option[1][]:2
bundle_option_qty[
    1][2]:1
bundle_option[1][]:3
bundle_option_qty[
    1][3]:
```

I Have the correct qty sent.

But in my cart i see this:

```
1 x XXXXX
1 x XXXXX
1 x XXXXX
```

What could i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that i send the Data in 2 lines, so it´s not the same as normal.

It must be

```
product:712
related_product:
bundle_option[1][]:1
bundle_option_qty[1][1]:3
bundle_option[1][]:2
bundle_option_qty[1][2]:1
bundle_option[1][]:3
bundle_option_qty[1][3]:
```

Tip: Never make space for nothing.